# I need assistance for my little program (python lists)

Tags: python, list

I will give you my python code (it's pretty basic and small) and if you can,tell me where i am wrong.I am noob at coding so your help will be valuable.thanks a lot and don't hate :)

```
lista=[]
for i in range(100):
    a=input("give me  a number")
    if a%2==0:
        a=0
    else:
        a=1
    lista=lista+a
print lista
```

P.S: I code with python 2 because my school books are written with that in mind.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What is the expected and actual behavior of your code? Also, you may want to read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11082165)

Comment: You can add a list to a list: `lista += [a]`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [append](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) method to add an item to the end of the list.

```
lista.append(a)
```

And you need to convert the `str` returned by [input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) to int.

> The input() function reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that. When EOF is read, EOFError is raised.

```
a = int(input("give me  a number"))
```

Try this:

```
lista=[]
for i in range(2): # Changed from 100 to 2 for my own testing
    a = int(input("Give me  a number: "))
    a = 1 if a%2 else 0
    lista.append(a)
print(lista)
```

Outputs:

```
[0,1]
```

**EDITED:**

> So i cant use Lista=lista +a?I thought i could..my book says i can..thanks for your solution,it works!

You can use `+=` operator (similar to `extend()`) but it requires a `list` operand. Not an `int`. So, you need to convert your int to a list. Try this:

```
lista += [a]
```

`list.append(a)` is faster, because it doesn't create a temporary list object. So, better to use `append`.

Comment: So i cant use Lista=lista +a?I thought i could..my book says i can..thanks for your solution,it works!